# Wedding in May (US) - Family in China and Covid-19 travel restriction

Tags: covid-19

My wedding is at the end of May in the US and we have family (non-US citizens) living in both Shanghai and southern Italy. As of now my understanding is there is a two week restriction on non-US citizens living in China before they can enter the US.

We do not want to have the wedding without our family there and are wondering if we should post pone to a later date.

I know this is an open-ended question but what is the likelihood on more or less travel restrictions in May?

Comment: Absolutely impossible to answer.

Comment: How much later would you be willing to postpone to? Are we talking a couple of weeks or would you be willing to push the date back by a whole year if need be?

Comment: Given current precedent, it seems likely there will be more restrictions on travel before they walk them back but as said before, impossible to say with any certainty

Comment: I know this is impossible for answer and leaves open to many opinions but we would be willing to push back a year.

Comment: @Matt seeing what's happening in the world, my guess would be no bans will be lifted in the next 6 months. So postponing for a year is not unreasonable! But don't be surprised if even after one year the ban will still be there.  Beaurocracy moves slowly, even after the COVID-19 situation starts improving, it will take countries a while to start feeling safe again to life immigration restrictions. It's always easier to ban stuff than lift a ban.

Comment: To avoid the ban, your family members in China could travel to some place outside Mainland China (even Hong Kong would work) for 14 days first, and then travel to the US. The US does not currently have a ban on people who've been to Italy but that may change in the future.

Comment: The problem is the cost to stay somewhere for 14 days and then travel to the US. Also having vacation days.